# Exec-ing a program within tcl with redirection

Tags: tcl

Within a tcl program I am trying to exec a program which takes input using <

```
puts [exec "./program < inputfile"]
```

However, this produces the error

```
couldn't execute "./program < inputfile": no such file or directory
```

Is there a way of doing this in tcl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tcl can process redirections itself, so you would write:

```
puts [exec ./program <inputfile]
```

Otherwise, it tries to interpret the whole thing as a single (somewhat strange) filename; legal (on Unix, not on Windows) but not what you wanted.

Alternatively, you can fire the whole thing off through the system shell:

```
puts [exec /bin/sh -c "./program < inputfile"]
```

That works, but has *many* caveats. In particular, quoting things for the shell is a non-trivial problem, and you're not portable to Windows (where the incantation for running things through the command-line processor is a bit different). You also have an extra process used, but that's not really a big problem in practice unless you're *really* stretching the limits of system resources.

The plus side is that you can use full shell syntax in there, which can do a few things that are downright awkward otherwise. It's also more widely known, so something I'd surface to users with a medium level of expertise. (New users should stick to canned stuff; real experts can write some Tcl scripts.)

Comment: This is expanding on Chhama's self-answer, which is entirely right.

Answer (score 2):

I found out the answer, the command has to be written as

```
puts [exec "./program" < inputfile]
```